# Kubernetes EKS, AWS CodeBuild & AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-lambda

I made an containerized application using ECR, EKS.

For my CI-CD pipeline, I have AWS Code pipeline:

- AWS Code Commit - GitHub
- AWS CodeBuild that will automatically perform build tasks such us building the app in a docker image, tag the image and lastly push the image to ECR.

In my deploy process I need it to be on AWS pipeline so I turn to AWS Lambda that can execute functions to rollout an update; However, in libraries such as kubernetes python, nodeJS client. There is no API that will do the `kubectl rollout restart deployment`. My deployment process is pretty simple do a rollout update withoun any change in image tag (the same image tag)

Comment: This is one reason why using the `latest` tag or reusing a tag is highly not recommended.

Comment: considering that I don't have static tag like latest. In the py kubernetes library it's required to always create a deployment object which will be difficult incase I have an update with the deployment.yaml I will always need to update the lambda py function to align with that deployment config.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a deploy tool for kubernetes, in my current setup I'm using samson and a lambda function to let samson knows when there is a new image pushed to ecr, when it occours you can then deploy the new image to your kubernetes cluster.

Comment: I already have CI CD pipeline in place what I did is to use AWS Code Pipeline; 

CodeCommit -> CodeBuild -> Lambda Deployment (Python)

However the set up is via k8spy patch_namespaced_deployment; What I'm trying to do is to have a rollout deplotment approach; patch_namespaced_deployment is a all at once approach that will have downtime;